# Have values of Index Signatures in Typescript to be explicitly declared as optional?

Tags: typescript

I declared a Typescriptobject as index signature (`{[k:t]: v}`). When I access one of its elements without ensuring that "undefined" is returned I expect typescript to mark this as a potential error:

```
let obj: { [x: number]: number } = {};
console.log(obj[123].toFixed());     // <-- I expect typescript warns me that obj[123] could be undefined!
```

But actually this is not the case although **every** javascript object will have some undefined keys which return undefined. Thus to ensure that I get the warning I had to declare `obj` like:

```
let obj: { [x: number]: number|undefined } = {};
```

My question: What is the idiomatic solution of typescript? Is it always add "|undefined" to the value of index signatures? Or is there another way of ensuring that the compiler will warn me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to warn you whenever you use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) property value without checking for `undefined` first, you can enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess).  This gives you the error you expected:

```
let obj: { [x: number]: number } = {};
console.log(obj[123].toFixed());  // error!
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

However, there's a reason this isn't part of the "standard" [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  It turns out that this makes some idiomatic JavaScript quite annoying:

```
function iterArr(arr: string[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i].toUpperCase()); // error!
        //Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
}
```

The compiler can't tell the difference between "good" indexes and "bad" indexes for index signature types.  Your choices are basically to configure the compiler either to always unsafely assume the value is present or always complain that the value might be absent.

For that reason I would generally just leave `--noUncheckedIndexedaccess` off and manually add `undefined` to the domain of the value for types you care about, as you've done:

```
let obj: { [x: number]: number | undefined } = {};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAUEnSA2EALkgPYBGAVgFwZIDaAHjcAK5hkQBOAus2x5yQBfJAF4MQgNzZc8EsCgkCAOjwkA5gApyFOgEYATAGZuywiQBiASwYQAJpoCUjyTgD0bpF04lOAQhl3TwB5Sgh4YisoJBgSKCgrMjwATyQAchZgOwgAMytgezTlTECkHMyIq3kkK0IuAEFOTk0QJpooQk589TpuRwxS3DLfJE0CSLEkAAZXKyQAHiRWzlUIYHVCAAtZgGod-qwho9l5RRU1LWW6K1NzAFUYGC4AYRAoCCcXJA8vJt8A47HDyhCjhSLRWLxRIpdKZbJ5Ap2IqDXBCUpotGYUCQWAIZAATQGQ3GpEoNHQ9CYSFY7C4vGp-C4SAAPkg4bl8vZhJN0FJSnIFEoIKoNNpKPpjLdLDZ7J9XEMfvMALRKpAASS8DCeESQhGSTyg8C6MGIAHdWgokJBdZsQMQdBKTEg5Cw8HYkBw2VkOYiAkIgA)